# Remove empty value before converting string to array

Tags: ruby, arrays, split

```
ids = "1,4,5,"

ids.split(',') => ["1", " 4", " 5", " "]

ids.split(',').map(&:to_i) => [1, 4, 5, 0]
```

How do I remove that empty value before it becomes a zero?

Comment: Given the spaces in your result for `ids.split(',')`, there must be extra spaces in your original `ids` variable.  I'm guessing it's actually `"1, 2, 3, "` (with a space after each comma)?  If you split what you have shown, you do not get that extra element.  Please copy and paste your code exactly to avoid this confusion.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Are you reading the data from a file and asking how to process individual lines? If so, use the [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class and save yourself headaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) also

```
ids = "1,4,5,"
ids.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
# => [1, 4, 5]
```

Comment: As long as the values are integers this will work. If there are floating point or any string elements it will fail.

Comment: @theTinMan Then the code I'll change for sure. This is given as per the OP's example.

Comment: Right, that's true, however, `split` will return a more useful result than `scan` in the case of variant types of data.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't happen in Ruby 2.2+:

```
ids = "1,4,5,"
ids.split(',')
# => ["1", "4", "5"]

RUBY_VERSION # => "2.2.0"
```

The simple thing to do is run a preflight check on your data and normalize it to what it's supposed to be, BEFORE trying to process it:

```
ids = "1,4,5,"

ids.chop! if ids[-1] == ','
ids # => "1,4,5"

ids.split(',')
# => ["1", "4", "5"]
```

You could be a bit more rigorous in the test, since the end of the line might also contain whitespace which would throw off the cleanup.

Also, you're dealing with comma-delimited data, so consider using the built in [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class, which is designed to work with such strings.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that change, which I'm glad to see. In case anyone is wondering, in v.2.2 we still get `",1,2,3".split(',') #=> ["", "1", "2", "3"]`.

Comment: This is [not new behaviour](https://ideone.com/UREVr9). Quoting the doc: "If the limit parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are suppressed. "